# Trying to assign integer values to things stored in a list & error message"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'random' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to write a function that allows a user to play a card drawing game against a computer. In doing this, I use a list to store all 52 cards in a deck of cards but when the user or computer draws one, the code is supposed to remove that card from the list. It was working until I put the code into a function and defined it. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I also cannot seem to find a way to assign each card in a deck of cards an integer value to match it (ex. 2 of Clubs should have a value of 2 and K of Hearts should have a value of 13). If anyone has answers to either of these problems, it would be appreciated.

*Note the code is not completely finished and I know there are some other logic flaws, but I'm stuck on these errors in particular.

```
# Useful Definitions
user_score = 0
computer_score = 0
type = "user"
winner = "none"
import random
card_list = ['1 Clubs', '2 Clubs', '3 Clubs', '4 Clubs', '5 Clubs', '6 Clubs', '7 Clubs', '8 Clubs', '9 Clubs', '10 Clubs', '11 Clubs', '12 Clubs', '13 Clubs', '1 Hearts', '2 Hearts', '3 Hearts', '4 Hearts', '5 Hearts', '6 Hearts', '7 Hearts', '8 Hearts', '9 Hearts', '10 Hearts', '11 Hearts', '12 Hearts', '13 Hearts', '1 Spades', '2 Spades', '3 Spades', '4 Spades', '5 Spades', '6 Spades', '7 Spades', '8 Spades', '9 Spades', '10 Spades', '11 Spades', '12 Spades', '13 Spades', '1 Diamonds', '2 Diamonds', '3 Diamonds', '4 Diamonds', '5 Diamonds', '6 Diamonds', '7 Diamonds', '8 Diamonds', '9 Diamonds', '10 Diamonds', '11 Diamonds', '12 Diamonds', '13 Diamonds',]



# Introduction code
print("Hello, Welcome to the Pig Card Game!")
user_name = input("What's your name? ")
cont = input("Press enter to learn how to play, " + user_name)
print()
print("***************************************************************")
print()


#Main Menu Function
def main_menu(name):
    print()
    print("What would you like to do, " + user_name + "?")
    print("1. Learn the Rules of Craps")
    print("2. Play!!")
    print("3. Exit.")
    choice = input("Enter your selection: ")
    print("*****************************************************")
    print()
    return choice
    

# Instructions
def game_rules():
    
    print("1. In the game, you will play against the computer in a luck-based")
    print("card game.")
    print("2. During your turn, you will draw a random card from  standard")
    print("deck of cards.")
    print("Each card is worth its standard numerical value - A 2 is worth 2")
    print("points and a King is worth 13 Points")
    print("3. You may choose to continue your turn as long as you want, by")
    print("drawing more random cards and adding those to your point total.")
    print("4. However, if at any point in your turn, you draw an ace or a")
    print("jack of any suit, you will lose all of your points collected in")
    print("your turn and your turn will end.")
    print("5. The first player to reach a score of 50 points loses.")
    print()
    cont = input("Press enter to go back to the main menu")
    print()
    print("***************************************************************")
    print()


def game_turn(type):
    
    while user_score != 50 and computer_score != 50:
        
        if type == "user":
            user_turn_score = 0
            cont = input("It is your turn, " + user_name + ". Press enter to draw a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(card_list)
            print("Your card: " + random_drawn_card)
            card_list.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "1 Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "1 Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "1 Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "1 Spades" or random_drawn_card == "11 Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "11 Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "11 Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "11 Spades":
                user_turn_score = 0
                print("You drew an Ace or a Jack. You will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "computer"
            else:
                user_turn_score = user_turn_score
                print("Your total score: " + str(user_score))
                turn_type = input("Do you want to continue your turn? (Y/N) ")
                if turn_type == "Y":
                    type = "user"
                else:
                    type = "computer"
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()
        
        elif type == "computer":
            computer_turn_score = 0
            print("It is the computer's turn. Drawing a random card.")
            random_drawn_card = random.choice(card_list)
            print("Computer's Card: " + random_drawn_card)
            card_list.remove(random_drawn_card)
            if random_drawn_card == "A Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "A Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "A Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "A Spades" or random_drawn_card == "J Clubs" or random_drawn_card == "J Hearts" or random_drawn_card == "J Diamonds" or random_drawn_card == "J Spades":
                computer_turn_score = 0
                print("The computer drew an Ace or a Jack. It will not gain any points this turn.")
                type = "user"
            else:
                computer_turn_score = computer_turn_score
                print("Computer's total score: " + str(computer_score))
                import random
                computer_turn = random.randint(1,2)
                if computer_turn == 1:
                    type = "computer"
                    print("The computer will take another turn.")
                else:
                    type = "user"
                    print("The computer will not take another turn.")
            print()
            print("***************************************************************")
            print()


main_choice = main_menu(user_name)

#Loop that encompasses the entire game that determines if user goes to rules, plays, or leaves
while main_choice != "3":
    
    if main_choice == "1":
        game_rules()
    elif main_choice == "2":
        user = game_turn(type)
    else:
        print("Invalid Selection. Choose a number between 1 and 3.")

    main_choice = main_menu(user_name)
    
    
#Outro message to user
print("Thanks for playing, " + user_name + ". See you next time!")
```

Comment: Can you paste the full traceback

Comment: Get rid of the `import random` inside `game_turn`. You don't need to import `random` multiple times.

Comment: Remove the import of ```import random``` under ```print("Computer's total score: " + str(computer_score))```. Always import them at the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to your question "cannot seem to find a way to assign each card in a deck of cards an integer value to match it (ex. 2 of Clubs should have a value of 2 and K of Hearts should have a value of 13)"? This is how I implement all card games requiring a deck of cards:

```
from random import shuffle, choice
from collections import namedtuple
from enum import Enum 
CARD = namedtuple("Card", "suit, rank")
class SUITS(Enum):
    Clubs = 1
    Diamonds = 2
    Hearts = 3
    Spades = 4
class RANKS(Enum):
    Two = 2
    Three = 3
    Four = 4
    Five = 5
    Six = 6
    Seven = 7
    Eight = 8
    Nine = 9
    Ten = 10
    Jack = 11
    Queen = 12
    King = 13
    Ace = 1

class Deck:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.cards = []
        self.discards = [CARD(suit, rank) for suit in SUITS for rank in RANKS]
        self.inPlay = []
        self.shuffle_deck
    
    @property    
    def shuffle_deck(self):
        """Shuffle the deck after adding in the discard pile"""
        shuffle(self.discards)
        shuffle(self.discards)
        self.cards.extend(self.discards)
        shuffle(self.cards)
        
    @property
    def deal(self, amount, withdiscard= True):
        """deal amount number of cards, if not 
           enough cartds, reshuffle the deck"""
        if len(self.cards) < amount:
            self.shuffle_deck()
        k = tuple(self.cards.pop() for _ in range(amount))
        for crd in k:
            if withdiscard:
                self.discards.append(crd)
            else:
                self.inPlay.append(crd)
        return k
    
    @property
    def drawCard(self, withdiscard= True):
        """draw a single card, if no cards left, 
           reshuffle the deck"""
        if len(self.cards) == 0:
            self.shuffle_deck
        crd = choice(self.cards)
        self.cards.remove(crd)
        if withdiscard:
            self.discards.append(crd)
        else:
            self.inPlay.append(crd)
        return crd
```

Then by executing:

```
dk = Deck()
crd = dk.drawCard
```

You will get:

```
Card(suit=<SUITS.Diamonds: 2>, rank=<RANKS.Three: 3>)
```

and you can access the suit as `crd.suit.name` it's value/rank as `crd.rank.value` and its rank as `crd.rank.name`

Comment: Is there a way to have that stored in a list? For this code I need to use a list to store the card. Thanks.

Comment: You can simply replace the lines ```            random_drawn_card = random.choice(card_list)
            print("Your card: " + random_drawn_card)
            card_list.remove(random_drawn_card)``` with the lines ```random_drawn_card = dk.drawCard   print(f"Your Card is {random_drawn_card.rank.name} of {random_drawn_card.suit.name}'s")```